# Running gcc 5.2 build on gcc 4.4.7 Red Hat 6.6

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc

We built an exe using gcc 5.2 (g++ and --std=c++14 if that matters).

Our current deployment machine:
$ cat /etc/red*
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

It has following libc:
$ /lib/libc-2.12.so
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-9).
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.32 system on 2015-01-19.

Before running this exe, we made sure that it will use the various dependent libraries built with gcc5.2.0 which were used during the build process.

However as the below output of "lsof -p" shows, there are still some libraries (basically everything under "/lib64" in the first few lines below) being used which are from the gcc 4.4.7 build. Could this be an issue?

```
     NODE NAME
      130 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
      154 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
     8296 /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
     8294 /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
     1778 /lib64/libm-2.12.so
     8315 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
      218 /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
     5312 /lib64/librt-2.12.so
     5663 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
  4199459 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libgcc_s.so.1
  4199412 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libstdc++.so.6
  4199453 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libboost_regex.so.1.61.0
  4199433 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libboost_date_time.so.1.61.0
  4199442 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libboost_filesystem.so.1.61.0
  4199427 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libboost_system.so.1.61.0
  4199476 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libboost_thread.so.1.61.0
  4199429 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libxerces-c-3.0.so
  4199407 /home/gcc-5.2.0/runtime_libs/libACE.so.6.2.0
```

Comment: The new instance with gcc5.2 build seems to be working fine but still concerned about this mix of gcc 4.4.7 libs and gcc 5.2 libs

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `libstdc++.so.6` with your own copy can be problematic because it is a system library, and as such can be used by other system libraries.  Whether this works in practice depends on how carefully your version of `libstdc++.so.6` has been prepared.

The different GCC versions part of [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/) avoid this problem because they use a hybrid linkage model, where the bulk of the system `libstdc++.so.6` library is still used, and the functionality needed by newer C++ versions is included through static linking.